# redux state not changing

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm using a Net Core, React-Redux boiler-plate, and when I run the fetch api action, the reducer state does not change at all.

Here is my action

```
import axios from "axios";
import config from '../config';

const ROOT_URL = config[process.env.NODE_ENV].api;

export const FETCH_EVENTS = "FETCH_EVENTS";
export function fetchEvents() {
    const url = ROOT_URL +"/Event/GetAllEvents";
    const request = axios.get(url);

    return {
        type: FETCH_EVENTS,
        payload: request
    };
}
```

my index reducer:

```
import { combineReducers} from 'redux';
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';
import dataReducer from './dataReducer'

    const reducers = {
        events: dataReducer
    };

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    routing: routerReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

and my reducer:

```
import { FETCH_EVENTS } from "../actions/ExtractActions";

export default function (state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_EVENTS:
            console.log("inside reducer")
            return [action.payload, ...state];
    }
    return state;
}
```

So I add this code in the Home component:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ fetchEvents }, dispatch);
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        events: state.events
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

but when I try to run the action and try to see if the reducer state has changed, I get on console log an empty array for "this.props.events". Even though if I am trying to store api data to the state, I even tried modifying the reducer method and simply returning a string, but this.props.events returns an empty array [] again. I am guessing my redux is not working but I don't know why. I've been debugging all night long

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchEvents()
    console.log(this.props.events)

}
```

Comment: I think you should use either `await` or `callback` when you call `axios.get(url)`. Since it is asynchronous

Comment: even if I return{
        type: FETCH_EVENTS,
        payload: "hello"
    };  I still won't see the hello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. For some reason I had to call this.props.events in the render() method and not componentwillmount.

Answer (score 0):

axios.get() is an async function. That's why you couldn't see the updated state when you logged it right after fetching the events. I would recommend you to use the [redux-devtools-extension](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-devtools-extension) for debugging. Hope this helps. Cheers!